# How do i change my locale safely?

Tags: bash, bashrc, locale

**1) How do I check which locales are supported on my system?**

**2) How do I change my locale safely?**

**3) What are some of the side-effects of doing this?**

Reason I'm asking these questions is because I want to use a different collating sequence rather from the proper dictionary order so I can use regular expressions globally, but I'm not sure how this will affect pathname expansions.

Answer (score 0):

To check which locales have been generated and are currently available to use, run:

```
locale -a
```

To check 'the current locale', i.e. which locales have been set for the various locale categories, run:

```
locale
```

There is a designated collate locale category: `LC_COLLATE`. If you want to change that category only, without affecting other locale categories, you can edit your `~/.profile` file and add a line similar to:

```
export LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
```

When doing so, you should pick a locale which has already been generated. To manually generate an additional locale, you can run:

```
sudo locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8
```